# Custom command for Run/Debug configurations in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to run a custom (shell) command from the Run/Debug configuration system in IntelliJ? I'm working with a framework that is not yet supported at all by IntelliJ (PhoneGap) and I want to add a few commands there.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

> Edit Configurations > Before Launch > Add > Run External Tool

Answer (score 0):

You can you *Batch script plugin* if you have windows or *BashSupport* for linux (and probably mac) os.

By putting `bat` or `sh` file inside your project you can execute them by adding new run configuration.